# selenium-manager.exe doesn't exist

Tags: python-3.x, windows, selenium-webdriver, pyinstaller

The problem exist only in Windows, in Linux the same code compiles without problems.
It worked previously in Windows as well, i don't know what changed.
Versions of pyinstaller(6.3.0) and selenium(4.17.2) are the same for both Windows and Linux.

Compiling on Windows gives me an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\pyinstaller\\bincache01py31164bit\\selenium\\webdriver\\common\\windows\\selenium-manager.exe'
```

Original part of the code:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

i've tried to:

- remove folders bincache01py31164bit, build and *spec file
- change driver:

  ```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\Arhiv\\Install_Configure\\python-environments\\certs_env\\Scripts\\geckodriver.exe", options=options)

    ser = Service()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=ser, options=options)

    ser = Service(r"C:\Arhiv\Install_Configure\python-environments\certs_env\Scripts\geckodriver.exe")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=ser, options=options)
  ```

Nothing worked. Any ideas?

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Arhiv\Install_Configure\python-environments\certs_env\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Arhiv\Install_Configure\python-environments\certs_env\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 214, in _console_script_run
    run()
  File "C:\Arhiv\Install_Configure\python-environments\certs_env\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 198, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Arhiv\Install_Configure\python-environments\certs_env\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 69, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Arhiv\Install_Configure\python-environments\certs_env\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1071, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\Arhiv\Install_Configure\python-environments\certs_env\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1011, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "D:\admin\Source\main_gui.spec", line 18, in <module>
    exe = EXE(
          ^^^^
  File "C:\Arhiv\Install_Configure\python-environments\certs_env\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 609, in __init__
    self.pkg = PKG(
               ^^^^
  File "C:\Arhiv\Install_Configure\python-environments\certs_env\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 238, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Arhiv\Install_Configure\python-environments\certs_env\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Arhiv\Install_Configure\python-environments\certs_env\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 329, in assemble
    CArchiveWriter(self.name, bootstrap_toc + archive_toc, pylib_name=self.python_lib_name)
  File "C:\Arhiv\Install_Configure\python-environments\certs_env\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\archive\writers.py", line 141, in __init__
    toc_entry = self._write_entry(fp, entry)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Arhiv\Install_Configure\python-environments\certs_env\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\archive\writers.py", line 226, in _write_entry
    return self._write_file(fp, src_name, dest_name, typecode, compress=compress)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Arhiv\Install_Configure\python-environments\certs_env\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\archive\writers.py", line 246, in _write_file
    data_length = os.stat(src_name).st_size
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\pyinstaller\\bincache01py31164bit\\selenium\\webdriver\\common\\windows\\selenium-manager.exe'
```

===================== EDIT =========================

Apparently selenium is good but pyinstaller for Windows doesn't work starting with 6.0.0 or it works somehow differently, i've yet to bug report. The last working version is 5.13.2 gives this output(PATH variable contents that's absent in 6 versions):

```
719 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (PATH): ['C:\\Arhiv\\Install_Configure\\python-environments\\certs_env\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin', 'C:\\Arhiv\\Install_Configure\\python-environments\\certs_env\\Scripts', 'C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\Scripts\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath', 'C:\\Windows\\system32', 'C:\\Windows', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\', 'D:\\mssql\\86\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\DTS\\Binn\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\Meld\\', 'D:\\mssql\\64\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\', 'D:\\mssql\\86\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\', 'D:\\mssql\\64\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\', 'D:\\mssql\\64\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\DTS\\Binn\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\PuTTY\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\', 'C:\\Arhiv\\Install_Configure\\python-environments\\certs_env\\Scripts\\', 'C:\\Users\\u18\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps', 'C:\\Program Files\\Azure Data Studio\\bin']
```